# Show $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (f_{n_k}, g) = (f,g)$ for a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ and $g$ in $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I would like to show that for any sequence $f_n(x) \in L^2([0,1])$ with $||f_n||_2=1$ for all $n$, there exists an $f\in L^2([0,1])$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that for every $g\in L^2([0,1])$ one has:

$lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (f_{n_k}, g) = (f,g)$

Here $(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(x)\cdot g(x) dx$ is the scalar product.

The given solution states: Let $(g_j)$ enumerate a countable dense subset. Then $(f_n,g_1)$ is totally bounded and so has a convergent subsequence. 
It then goes on to say that from that subsequence $(f_{n_k},g_2)$ is also totally bounded at which point I no longer follower their proof.

Any explanation or a different proof would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you need is the Banach Alouglu theorem - together with the fact that $L^2\cong (L^2)^{\ast}$.

Comment: Apparently, they are using a diagonalization argument.

Comment: I'd prefer a proof without the Banach Alouglu theorem, since we didn't discuss topologies in any great detail. The question was posed in a measure theory/Lebesgue integration course if that helps!

Comment: Have you shown in your course that $L^2$ is self-dual? i.e. that if $\ell(g)$ is a bounded linear functional of $g\in L^2$ then there is $f\in L^2$ with $\ell(g)=(f,g)$. This is what is needed after a suitable extraction of a subsequence.